# How to find the average of random integers in C#?

Tags: c#

I had the code working to print out 1000 random integers and find the min and max. I could only find a Java example for finding the average of those numbers. I'm not sure how to edit it to work for C#.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int min = int.MaxValue,
        max = int.MinValue;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1001; i++){
            int n = r.Next();
            n = n + i; 
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            if (n < min)
                min = n;
            if (n > max)
                max = n;

            for (n = 1 ; n <= 1001 ; x++) 
            {
                sum += numbers [n]; 
                average = sum / 1000; 

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Min = {0}, Max = {1} Sum = {2}", min, max, sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you starting your index @ 1?

Comment: What does the line n=n+i do? Also, I think you have some braces in the wrong place.

Comment: Just move `average = sum / 1000; ` outside the `for`.

Comment: for (n = 1 ; n <= 1001 ; x++) , should it be for (int x = 0 ; x <= 1000 ; x++), sum += numbers [x]; 
then move out your average = sum / 1000; after for loop

Comment: You need to format your code better. It's difficult to see the structure in the format you have.

Comment: Is this homework? A learning exercise?

Comment: I'm sure I have lots of mistakes. I've only started learning C# in a course. Its homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> RandomIntegers(int count)
{
    var random = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        yield return random.Next();
}
```

Then, use LINQ:

```
var average = RandomIntegers(1000).Average();
```

If you want the min/max/avg, do this:

```
var intList = RandomIntegers(1000).ToList();
var min = intList.Min();
var max = intList.Max();
var avg = intList.Average();
```

You have to call `ToList()` here so that you reuse the same sequence for the 3 next calls. If you didn't do this, you'd compute the min of a sequence, the max of another, and the average of yet another one.

This technique is more readable IMO than the *java way*.

---

As for the *oldschool* way:

```
Random r = new Random();

int min = int.MaxValue,
    max = int.MinValue;
long sum = 0;

const int count = 1000;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    int n = r.Next();
    sum += n;

    if (n < min)
        min = n;

    if (n > max)
        max = n;
}

double avg = (double)sum / count;
Console.WriteLine("Min = {0}, Max = {1}, Sum = {2}, Avg = {3}", min, max, sum, avg);
```

You have to compute the average just once, at the end.

Comment: I don't think introducing LINQ at this point is going to help the OP much. If the fundamentals aren't there yet it just adds too much confusion. Just try to explain the `yield return` to a beginner, let alone why you suddenly need the `.ToList()`...

Comment: I disagree @Medo42, the concept of not rewriting methods that are available in the framework is one that should be learned.  Maybe the use of the yield return and single evaluation by calling ToList is excessive for the answer, but the use of Linq to perform the mathematical functions is a very good idea.

Comment: But if you don't learn the underlying principles then you are lost when you come to use another language that doesn't have that feature. If you are learning the language then it sometimes pays to do it the 'hard' way.

Comment: Then again, SO is not the place to learn language fundamentals.

Comment: I added the classic way since there's controversy over LINQ.

Comment: I love LINQ. In the real world I'd definitely use it here. But OP is not trying to solve a real-world problem, they are probably trying to learn certain language fundamentals by solving an example problem. Showing a LINQ solution is like saying "Just use a calculator" to someone who is trying to learn manual multiplication.

Comment: @L-Three Where would be a good place to learn language fundamentals?

Comment: Read a book or watch screencasts.